# HTML transition images and one figcaption

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem and can't find a solution. I believe it's quit easy, but I can't find a way to work.
I have two images, one of them is only seen at hovering. I need to get a Figcaption to it. At the moment I use a second div box underneath the image div box, but thats not a nice way to solve my problem.

> ### HTML code
>
> ```
>     <div class="vid-pre-3 vid-marg">
>         <a href="http://www.mypage.com/">
>             <div id="vid-trans">
>                 <img class="width-100" src="http://www.mypage.com/preview/image02.png"/>
>                 <img id="top" class="width-100" src="http://www.mypage.com/preview/image01.png"/>
>             </div>
>         </a>
>     </div>
> ```
>
> ### CSS
>
> ```
> .vid-pre-3{
> width: 22.75%;
> float: left;
> height: 175px;
> }
> .vid-marg{
> margin-right: 3%;
> }
> #vid-trans{ 
> position: relative;
> }
> #vid-trans img#top:hover { 
> opacity:0 ;
> }
> #vid-trans img { 
> position: absolute; 
> top: 0; left: 0; opacity: 1;    
> transition: opacity 1s;
> }
> ```
>
> This is working, if I don't have a transition:

```
<div class="vid-pre-3 vid-marg">
    <img class="width-100" src="http://www.mypage.com/preview/image02.png" />
    <figcaption>My Caption Text</figcaption>
</div>
```

I'm happy for any solution!

Comment: You want the <figcaption> only visible on hover when the second image is visible?

Comment: I need it always visible. It's always behind the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand your question, but I think you're asking how to only show the figcaption on hover which you could do like this:

```css
.vid-pre-3{
  width: 22.75%;
  float: left;
  height: 175px;
}
.vid-marg{
  margin-right: 3%;
}
#vid-trans{ 
  position: relative;
}
#vid-trans:hover img#top { 
  opacity:0;
}
#vid-trans img { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; left: 0; opacity: 1;    
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

figcaption {
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
}
  #vid-trans:hover figcaption {
    display:block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="vid-pre-3 vid-marg">
  <a href="http://www.mypage.com/">
    <div id="vid-trans">
      <img class="width-100" src="http://placehold.it/250x250"/>
      <img id="top" class="width-100" src="http://placehold.it/250x250/fff/000"/>
      <figcaption>My Caption Text</figcaption>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Need to keep hold of that code, but it's not what I wanted ;)
I need some random Text underneath every image. Visible all the time. 
It's no big deal under one image, but if I use the transition the text is always behind the image. Hope I could explain myself now. Your code is on the image. But thanks for trying understanding me